# What happened to the changelog on QGIS 3 plugin info page?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.X the changelog from the `metadata.txt` was/is displayed on the plugins info page (and besides, the info whether a plugin is trusted or not):

[image]

In QGIS 3 I miss both informations:

[image]

Users are justifiably interested in such changelogs, and often do not want to browse to some `metadata.txt`.

Do I miss a setting or is this intented? Or a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changelog is only visible for installed plugins, that didn't change between version 2 and 3. I don't know if that's intended.

The "trusted plugin" information removal is intended, because it's meaning was not very clear.  A plugin was marked "trusted" if it's author was known by the QGIS core developers, it didn't mean the plugin was better than other plugins. It also didn't mean the plugin got an extra quality check.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, just confirmed that this behaviour did no change from 2 to 3. Seems I never missed it until now...